# Showing DialogFragment after receiving response from HTTP Post sometimes crashes app with IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, illegalstateexception

I am receiving a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` when trying to show a `DialogFragment`. This is how the flow of showing this dialog goes:

1. Call server API using Android Volley
2. Response from HTTP Post
3. Parse the JSON and decide what to do with it (in background thread)
4. Using `LocalBroadcast Intent`, sends a `Broadcast` to my `Activity`
5. `Activity` handles the `Broadcast` and checks to see if the app is in the foreground
6. If app is in foreground, then show the `DialogFragment`

I thought that checking if the app is in the foreground would be enough to handle this error?

What would be a proper way to handle this `IllegalStateException`?

**Activity w/ show dialog method**

```
public void showUpdateAppDialog() {
    if (Helpers.isAppInForeground(this)) {
        mUpdateAppDialog = UpdateAppDialog.newInstance();
        mUpdateAppDialog.show(mFm, GlobalVars.TAG_UPDATE_APP_DIALOG);
    }
}
```

**Android Volley HTTP Post call with response handler**

```
public void versionCheck() {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put(GlobalVars.KEY_PLATFORM, "android");
        obj.put(GlobalVars.KEY_VERSION, Integer.toString(mPrefs.getAppVersion()));

        Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(final JSONObject response) {
                Log.v(TAG_VOLLEY_RESPONSE, GlobalVars.DEST_VERSION_CHECK + ": " + response.toString());

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        boolean updated = false;

                        try {
                            if (doesResponseContainError(response)) return;

                            if (response.has(GlobalVars.EVENT_VERSION_CHECK)) {
                                updated = Boolean.valueOf(response.getString(GlobalVars
                                        .EVENT_VERSION_CHECK));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        finally {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(GlobalVars.EVENT_RECEIVER);
                            intent.putExtra(GlobalVars.KEY_EVENT, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                                    GlobalVars.EVENT_HIDE_UPDATING_ICON,
                                    GlobalVars.EVENT_VERSION_CHECK)));
                            intent.putExtra(GlobalVars.KEY_IS_UPDATED, updated);
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        };

        sendPost(GlobalVars.DEST_VERSION_CHECK, obj, GlobalVars.DEST_VERSION_CHECK, responseListener);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

**Is app in foreground check**

```
public static boolean isAppInForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> tasks = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    return tasks.get(0).processName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName());
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1365)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1383)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
   at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:138)
   at com.walintukai.lovelup.MainActivity.showUpdateAppDialog(MainActivity.java:991)
   at com.walintukai.lovelup.MainActivity.onVersionCheck(MainActivity.java:1269)
   at com.walintukai.lovelup.MainActivity.access$1200(MainActivity.java:90)
   at com.walintukai.lovelup.MainActivity$10.onReceive(MainActivity.java:1142)
   at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
   at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
   at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: @AlexLockwood Great info! Thanks for the link. As I need to have this `DialogFragment` show from the result of an asynchronous call, do you have any recommendations as to handle my issue? Doesn't seem like a `Loader` is a proper fit for this?